# changing state in functional component not rendering as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, lifecycle, react-functional-component

Hello in this movie app I need to submit 2 times to get result. code & demo is here https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-lehmann-97c4o
Same problem in selecting pages needs to click on page two times to change.
Problem is occurring because in getList() & handleSubmit() "displayData" &"list" is not able to save any new state data they contain previous data.

What is right way to render this or setstate.

Comment: Can you explain how to use this demo to reproduce the bug? More information is needed

Comment: I'm not looking to much into it. But i can see `getList()` shouldn't be a function in a first place, instead you should use `useEffect(() => { getList code }, [list, offSet])`.

Comment: Ya thats the correct approach I did it using same way thanks. @jank